# Scala until loop with floating points

Tags: scala, loops, floating-point

With the code:

```
(0.0 until 0.5 by 0.9)
```

I expected the result to be `NumericRange(0.0)`
Instead, I got `NumericRange()`

When I try the same with a to:

```
(0.0 to 0.5 by 0.9)
```

I get the expected `NumericRange(0.0)`

with:

`(30 until 31 by 2)` I get `NumericRange(30)`

Which is what I would expect.

Can someone explain to me why until doesn't include the starting element in the floating point case?

Comment: just tried with until and got the correct result `scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange[Double] = NumericRange(0.0)` scala 2.10.2

Comment: @AlexIv: `NumericRange()` on `2.9.3`.

Comment: Then either it's a bug or a feature =)

Comment: @AlexIv. It's a bug: SI-4985.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug ([SI-4985](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4985)) in `NumericRange` implementation in `2.9.x`.

[Fixed](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/c0407608be3bd40e99dd2d86df6efb2446b1c1cd) in `2.10.x`.